# How to removed linked static web app in Azure Function's Authentication Identity Provider using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-static-web-app

There is `az staticwebapp backends unlink` command to unlink the static web app from the Azure Function app but this leaves the static web app linked still in the Azure Function's Authentication > Identity Provider section. This prevents linking a new static web app to the Azure Function.

What az cli command can remove this linked identity provider?

Answer (score 1):

[Updated] To remove an existing custom OpenID Connect identity provider, you can [use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/auth/openid-connect?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-auth-openid-connect-remove):

```
az webapp auth openid-connect remove
```

Comment: This is managed identity though and I am asking about identity provider

Comment: It does seems to be available for staticwebapp

Comment: This is not for staticwebapp. I'm asking about Azure Function App and its Identity Provider configuration, which has the "Azure Static Web Apps (Linked)" in it even after I unlink from the static web app side. Which value should I provide for `--provider-name` param of this command? If I use `--provider-name "Azure Static Web Apps"`, I get `Usage Error: The following custom OpenID Connect provider has not been configured: Azure Static Web Apps`